# Sorting formula in Excel

Tags: sorting, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have data that comes like this:

```
bear        94
cat         25
alligator   53
impala      55
elk         56
fox         47
dog         13
gecko       18
jaguar      32
hound       59
```

...but I would like to have two 'copies' of this table on the same Excel sheet, the first sorting on the first column, so like:

```
alligator   53
bear        94
cat         25
dog         13
elk         56
fox         47
gecko       18
hound       59
impala      55
jaguar      32
```

...and the second table would be again the same data, but sorting on the second column, like so:

```
bear        94
hound       59
elk         56
impala      55
alligator   53
fox         47
jaguar      32
cat         25
gecko       18
dog         13
```

...but the catch is that I ***don't*** want to have to use the actual 'sort' feature in excel! This may sound crazy, but I have a much larger application where manually sorting would be very tedious. If possible, I'd like to have a formula that does this automatically, but I could use an excel-VBA macro too. Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by the `sort` feature being manual / tedious? Since you just highlight the range and click `sort`, I am not sure why the size of the data set affects how tedious this would be. I guess you are saying you want a larger program to work without manual intervention in the middle?

Comment: What i mean is that the workbook has around a hundred sheets with custom ranges, etc., and would require several copy/pastes/sorts etc. It's a good point you make, but just trust me it would be really helpful if i can figure out the functionality I'm asking for

Comment: do all the sheets have the same column headings?

Comment: are you asking the data in the same relative place for all sheets? not necessarily :(

Comment: @Jenny_Winters OK, understood. It is certainly feasible to use the `SORT` function within VBA. But this will require some coding, especially to account for special cases (for example, you mentioned the applicable range moves around). If you give this a try, it is easier for us to help if you get stuck. If needed, you can use the `record macro` function in Excel to see the basic syntax details.

Comment: If you want a pure Excel formula solution without VBA I would suggest using `RANK()` to determine the position for each value in list and then `INDEX()/LOOKUP()` to pick the values in order... **HOWEVER**. This will only work for numeric column. There's no standard function to determine rank of text values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, here's the solution I came up with. Maybe there's a more elegant way, please let me know! Thanks guys :)

[image]

Comment: `B:B` column is genius!! You get +1!

Comment: @Taosique thanks, but it's stolen from here ;): http://chandoo.org/wp/2008/10/22/sorting-text-in-excel-using-formulas/

Comment: Because vlookup is slow for large data sets, I would change them to =INDEX(C$4:C$13,MATCH(ROW()-ROW(E$3),$B$4:$B$13,0)) and =INDEX(D$4:D$13,MATCH(ROW()-ROW(F$3),$B$4:$B$13,0)).  There is also a problem with the value sorted results if there are two or more "animals" with the same value.  It will only return the first name.

Comment: To solve the duplicate data issue:  Column A =VALUE(D4&"."&ROW())  Column G =INDEX($C$4:$C$13,MATCH(LARGE($A$4:$A$13,ROW()-ROW(I$3)),$A$4:$A$13,0))

Answer (score 1):

If you got a lot of sheets, VBA may be the way to go. The following code is one way to do this. It loops through all the sheets in a workbook and sorts each table (assuming that the sheet only holds that **one table** which begins in cell `A1`) by the variables you define in `SortBy1` and `SortBy2`.

It will sort the table by `SortBy2`, copy this beneath the original table and then sort the original table once more by `SortBy1`. This should work as long as the variables you want to sort by are all named the same throughout the entire workbook.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SortAndCopy()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim DataRng As Range
    Dim SortRng1 As Range, SortRng2 As Range
    Dim nr As Integer, nc As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim DataArr As Variant
    Dim SortBy1 As String, SortBy2 As String
    Dim nBelowTable As Integer
    Dim HeaderFound As Integer

    SortBy1 = "Animal"  '<~~ Define the first variable to sort by
    SortBy2 = "Count"   '<~~ Define the second variable to sort by
    nBelowTable = 5     '<~~ Defines how far below the original table you want to place a copy

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Loops through each individual sheets
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        HeaderFound = 0
        'Determines data range
        nr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        nc = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set DataRng = ws.Range("A1:" & ws.Cells(nr, nc).Address)

        'Determines ranges to sort by
        For i = 1 To nc Step 1
            If LCase(ws.Cells(1, i).Value) = LCase(SortBy1) Then
                Set SortRng1 = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, i).Address & ":" & ws.Cells(nr, i).Address)
                HeaderFound = HeaderFound + 1
            End If
            If LCase(ws.Cells(1, i).Value) = LCase(SortBy2) Then
                Set SortRng2 = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, i).Address & ":" & ws.Cells(nr, i).Address)
                HeaderFound = HeaderFound + 1
            End If
        Next i

        'Exit if header not found
        If Not HeaderFound = 2 Then
            MsgBox "One of the header variables could not be found in the sheet " & ws.Name & ". No further sheets will be processed!", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Sorts table by SortBy2
        With ws.Sort.SortFields
            .Clear
            .Add Key:=SortRng2, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        End With
        With ws.Sort
            .SetRange DataRng
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With

        'Places copy of this table underneath the original
        ReDim DataArr(1 To nr, 1 To nc)
        DataArr = DataRng
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(nr + nBelowTable, 1).Address, ws.Cells(2 * nr + nBelowTable - 1, nc).Address) = DataArr

        'Sorts table by SortBy1
        With ws.Sort.SortFields
            .Clear
            .Add Key:=SortRng1, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        End With
        With ws.Sort
            .SetRange DataRng
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With

    Next ws

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Comment: very powerful, but may be a little overkill for this application

Answer (score -2):

Get MOREFUNC addon for Excel and use VSORT()

---

**MOREFUNC ADDON**

- Morefunc Addon is a free library of 66 new worksheet functions.
- [HERE](http://web.archive.org/web/20111204011358/http://xcell05.free.fr/morefunc/english) is some information (by original author)
- here is the last working [download link](http://www.freewarefiles.com/downloads_counter.php?programid=14922) I found
- here is a good [installation walk-through video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAofPm4LCRc#t=92)

Answer (score -3):

Move to Google sheets and simply use [SORT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150)

Comment: ...Or write an console app in .NET that would open the file via ACE OleDB and sort it. The question is not about Google Sheets.